# CSS Text Flip Effect?

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions

It's been many a year since I used css (there was no such thing as css3 at the time) so I'm struggling to understand how, on the following page;

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/01/how-to-build-a-threaded-comment-block-with-html5-and-css3/

The red links do a sort of flip maneuver on hover, I've tried deciphering the underlying css with 'inspect element' but it's like spaghetti, I tried pasting the class in to my file and assigning it with little in the way of results.

Is there a formal name for this effect, or can anyone give me an idea as to how it can be replicated?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

class "roll-link" is doing the magic here. The transition and transform properties are doing the cool effects. When you see -webkit- and -moz- and others that means it is for those browsers because the properties are not standard yet but some browsers want to support them anyway.

```
/* ROLL LINKS */
.roll-link {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;

    vertical-align: top;

    -webkit-perspective: 600px;
       -moz-perspective: 600px;
       -ms-perspective: 600px;
       perspective: 600px;

    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
       -moz-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
       -ms-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
       perspective-origin: 50% 50%;

}

.roll-link:hover {text-decoration:none;}

.roll-link span {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 2px;

    -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
       -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
       -ms-transition: all 400ms ease;
       transition: all 400ms ease;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
       -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
       -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
       transform-origin: 50% 0%;

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.roll-link:hover span {
        background: #DD4D42;


        -webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
           -moz-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
           -ms-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
           transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
}

.roll-link span:after {
    content: attr(data-title);

    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0 2px;

    color: #fff;
    background: #DD4D42;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
       -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
       -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
       transform-origin: 50% 0%;

    -webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
       -moz-transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
       -ms-transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
       transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
}
```

This part for example:

```
.roll-link:hover span {
        background: #DD4D42;

        -webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
           -moz-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
           -ms-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
           transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
}
```

This means that span elements inside an element with the roll-link class when hovered on will apply these styles, but will cease application of these styles when not hovering on them.

The CSS transform property is a little complicated, having several parts. A lot of guys here do not like w3schools but they are a good starting point for introductory education. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: Yeah I got the class part but the rest of it looked completely alien and for whatever reason didn't work when I pasted it in. These examples do the job nicely, many thanks

Comment: Doesn't work for me on IE 11.  The original text rolls up, but the new text never appears.

Comment: @Gammadyne [Support is not full for IE 11](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d). I think the issue would be fixed if the HTML were written differently, such that it didn't depend on the nested spans. IOW, the text link that should appear needs to have the styles applied directly to it.

Answer (score 4):

Following is the code responsible for the rotation:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
-moz-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
-ms-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
```

#### Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Nds4/)

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to do the flip for the `li` rather than 'a'. Is that possible?